# Rasberry Pi 4 and display sleep wakes the display immediately again

Tags: display, power-management

Trying to figure out why the display I want in sleep mode immediately comes back on again when I tell it to sleep.

For example entering `xset dpms force off` in the Terminal and pressing *Enter* will make the display go to sleep, but then after a few seconds it automatically comes on again. I've tried to manually unplug all USB devices and let the display sleep without them in, but the display still comes on by itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be able to do this via [an HDMI CEC command](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/raspberry-pi-power-on-off-tv-connected.html).  Otherwise, you can't place the display in "sleep" because the display is built to come back on when there is a live input.   With a normal computer, the display will go to sleep when the computer does and wake when the computer is woken.  However (as I think you know) Rpis do not have any comparable form of power management.  The system is either on, or off -- there's no sleep.